# TypeError: 'str' object cannot interpreted as integer, в чем проблема?

Tags: python-3.x, файлы, tkinter

Сама Ошибка:[image: error]

Вообщем, есть у меня вот такие строчки кода:

```
if os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    self.closeTab()
    self.fileName = str(sys.argv[1])
    self.openID = randint(1, MAXINT32)
    infile = open(self.fileName, "r")
    new_text_file_name = os.path.basename(str(self.fileName))
    new_text = self.addTab(new_text_file_name)
    for line in infile:
        new_text.insert(END, line)
    new_text.hashStatus = md5(new_text.get(1.0, END).encode("utf-8"))
    infile.close()
```

Они берут путь с аргумента sys.argv, открывают файл по пути, и вставляют все символы из файла в текстовый виджет. Вообще такое происходит во всех функциях "open" неважно какой путь, флаг и т.д. На windows 8.1 такой ошибки не было, но когда я сегодня перешёл на десятку, то она появилась. В чем проблема?

Comment: и в какой же из этих строчек возникае ошибка? [ask]

Comment: ошибка возникает на infile = open(self.fileName, "r")

Comment: В этой строчке нет ничего про числа. Скопируйте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: "скопировать" означает выделить текст и вставить его в сообщение. А не скриншот. Почему вы думаете, что ошибка на строчке ``infile = open(self.fileName, "r")``?

Comment: 1. Скопировать не успеваю, успеваю только скриншот сделать и то не всегда т.к cmd вылетает почему то 2. потому что ошибка указывает на эту строку (1098)

Comment: ошибка из-за того, что где-то происходит попытка конвертировать строку в целое число, и это не получается (потому что число не целое или вообще в строке не число). А в это коде нет ничего похожего.

Comment: Питоны там и там одинаковые?

Comment: Да... Версия: 3.11.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я допёр. Стандартный метод "open", заменялся на "os.open" из-за того что я зачем-то не знаю импортировал всё из модуля "os". А не замечал из-за того что импорт был не в файле с ошибкой. Хотя её можно было заметить т.к метод "open" не подсвечивался как встроенный.

Comment: То есть вы делали `from os import *`? Это одна из тех вещей, которые рекомендуется не делать никогда, именно из-за возможного перекрытия сущностей.